# How do I get access to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) VAPID key?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to enable FCM for an existing firebase web app, but I'm having trouble generating the require VAPID key.

All tutorials (official Google docs and others) say it can be generated from the "Cloud Messaging" settings in the console, but this section isn't available to me (I only see `General`, `Integrations`, `Data privacy`, and `Users and permissions`. I confirmed that the FCM Registration API is enabled for my project, and Cloud Messaging is available for me in the left-hand menu (I was even able to set up and publish a message from the console). What could I be missing that I need in order to generate that VAPID key?

[my firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9hiV.png)

Comment: Which part of the instructions are you specifically having problems with?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#configure_web_credentials_with_fcm

Comment: `Generate a new key pair: 1. Open the Cloud Messaging tab of the Firebase console Settings pane and scroll to the Web configuration section.` .... when I open up Settings, I don't have the Cloud Messaging tab, only the four shown in the screenshot. As I noted I confirmed the API is enabled, and I can create a new message in the console itself-- my issue is just that "Cloud Messaging" just isn't appearing in the Settings page, so I can't generate the VAPID key

Comment: If the instructions don't make sense for your project, I suggest contacting Firebase support directly to explain what doesn't match.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support